# What does adding PATH to .bashrc do?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew

I'm following this guide to install Linux commands onto my OS Terminal: https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/ and I see that the second line tells me to add a line to my .bashrc file, which I have to create since I don't have one. Can anyone explain to me what this does? As well as the `PATH` command in general?

Answer (score 3):

When you run a command in `bash` (or any other Unix shell), the shell searches for this command in a number of directories. The list of directories is stored in the variable called `PATH`, paths are separated by `:`.

The command in question extends the already defined `$PATH` by two additional paths:

- `/usr/local/bin` which is the usual place user-provided commands get installed to
- The output of `$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin` which points to some utility commands required by brew

To see the current value of `PATH`, run `echo $PATH` in Terminal.

Comment: Additionally, the order `:` of the directories specified within one's `PATH` matters. The shell will search for the command according to that order.

Answer (score 1):

A .bashrc file can store and set a number of variables and commands that are executed (run) when you launch bash, which is one of many shells you can use to type commands into the Linux/Unix system.

For comparison, if you prefer the shell zsh then you would create a .zshrc file.